# Cannot Start Up Alfresco And Ephesoft Applications At The Same Time

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, connection, alfresco

Okay, so I had to install another instance of Alfresco (version 4.1.1) onto our server as our previous trial version had expired and we are still waiting to get a license. Previously we had Alfresco on port 8080 and Ephesoft on port 8081 and everything seemed to work fine.

Now after installing this new instance of Alfresco to port 8082, I cannot get both of them to start up at the same time.

In Alfresco's logs, I get the following error:

```
16:59:54,123 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
16:59:54,170 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
16:59:59,452 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.AbstractTriggerBean] Job ehCacheTracerJob is not active
17:00:01,936 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
17:00:01,952 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
17:00:05,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Schema managed by database dialect org.alfresco.repo.domain.hibernate.dialect.AlfrescoOracle9Dialect.
17:00:05,795 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] Bypassing schema update checks.
17:00:06,030 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module] preRegister called. Server=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6e70c7, name=log4j:logger=org.alfresco.repo.module
17:00:06,030 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] preRegister called. Server=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6e70c7, name=log4j:logger=org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper
17:00:06,280 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr]
17:00:06,358 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Search' subsystem, ID: [Search, managed, solr] complete
17:00:06,624 INFO  [org.alfresco.enterprise.repo.sync.SyncAdminServiceImpl] There is no key for cloud sync, cloud sync turned off
17:00:06,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default]
17:00:06,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'thirdparty' subsystem, ID: [thirdparty, default] complete
17:00:06,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default]
17:00:06,811 WARN  [org.alfresco.util.AbstractTriggerBean] Job openOfficeConnectionTesterTrigger is not enabled
17:00:06,936 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'OOoDirect' subsystem, ID: [OOoDirect, default] complete
17:00:06,936 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default]
17:00:07,545 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'OOoJodconverter' subsystem, ID: [OOoJodconverter, default] complete
17:00:07,545 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] The Alfresco root data directory ('dir.root') is: C:\Alfresco\alf_data
17:00:07,561 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] Checking for patches to apply ...
17:00:08,530 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.PatchExecuter] No patches were required.
17:00:08,545 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] Found 2 module(s).
17:00:08,577 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] Starting module 'org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart' version 1.0.
17:00:08,577 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Started module 'ModuleDetails[{module.version=1.0, module.description=Web Quick Start, module.id=org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart, module.repo.version.max=999, module.title=Web Quick Start, module.repo.version.min=3.3, module.installState=INSTALLED, module.installDate=2012-10-09T21:04:56.752-04:00}]' including 0components.
17:00:08,592 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleServiceImpl] Starting module 'org.alfresco.module.vti' version 1.2.
17:00:08,592 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Started module 'ModuleDetails[{module.version=1.2, module.description=Alfresco Vti Extension, module.id=org.alfresco.module.vti, module.repo.version.max=999, module.title=Vti, module.repo.version.min=0, module.installState=INSTALLED, module.installDate=2012-10-09T21:04:52.080-04:00}]' including 0components.
17:00:08,608 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Installed module found in distribution: org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart
17:00:08,608 DEBUG [org.alfresco.repo.module.ModuleComponentHelper] Installed module found in distribution: org.alfresco.module.vti
17:00:08,608 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default]
17:00:08,874 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1]
17:00:09,374 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1] complete
17:00:09,374 ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] No enabled CIFS authenticator found in authentication chain. CIFS Server disabled
17:00:09,389 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default] complete
17:00:09,389 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
17:00:09,467 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
17:00:09,467 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
17:00:09,499 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound] complete
17:00:09,499 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
17:00:09,592 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound] complete
17:00:09,592 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default]
17:00:09,624 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default] complete
17:00:09,624 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
17:00:09,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default] complete
17:00:09,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] Disabled - clear non-missing user usages ...
17:00:09,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] Found 0 users to clear
17:00:09,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] ... cleared non-missing usages for 0 users
17:00:09,639 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
17:00:09,670 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] Synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
17:00:09,686 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] Retrieving groups changed since Sep 11, 2012 3:54:45 PM from user registry 'ldap1'
17:00:09,702 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] ldap1 Group Analysis: Commencing batch of 0 entries
17:00:09,717 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] ldap1 Group Analysis: Completed batch of 0 entries
17:00:09,717 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] Retrieving users changed since Oct 9, 2012 2:39:10 PM from user registry 'ldap1'
17:00:09,717 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] ldap1 User Creation and Association: Commencing batch of 0 entries
17:00:09,717 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] ldap1 User Creation and Association: Completed batch of 0 entries
17:00:09,733 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] Finished synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
17:00:09,733 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] 0 user(s) and 0 group(s) processed
17:00:09,749 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default] complete
17:00:09,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco JVM - v1.6.0_33-b03; maximum heap size 682.688MB
17:00:09,858 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco license: Mode ENTERPRISE granted to Trial User limited to 30 days expiring Sat Nov 17 00:00:00 EST 2012 (30 days remaining).
17:00:09,858 INFO  [org.alfresco.service.descriptor.DescriptorService] Alfresco started (Enterprise). Current version: 4.1.1 (159) schema 5,115. Originally installed version: 4.1.1 (159) schema 5,115.
17:00:09,858 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
17:00:09,905 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default] complete
17:00:09,905 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
17:00:09,920 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default] complete
17:00:11,170 INFO  [org.alfresco.module.vti.VtiServer] Vti server started successfully on port: 7070
17:00:11,170 INFO  [org.alfresco.module.vti.VtiServer] Vti server SessionIdManagerWorkerName: jetty1
17:00:17,280 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 515 Web Scripts (+0 failed), 798 URLs
17:00:17,280 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 2 Package Description Documents (+0 failed) 
17:00:17,280 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] Registered 1 Schema Description Documents (+0 failed) 
17:00:17,280 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntimeContainer] Initialised Repository Web Script Container (in 4356.886ms)
17:00:17,280 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
17:00:17,296 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
17:00:31,389 ERROR [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] Job DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean#1353154 threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor] failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09180002 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09180002 
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:404)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:152)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.AbstractSearcherComponent.query(AbstractSearcherComponent.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy13.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor$1$1.execute(FeedbackProcessor.java:92)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:259)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor$1.doWork(FeedbackProcessor.java:82)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:516)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor.run(FeedbackProcessor.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:358)
    ... 28 more
17:00:31,389 ERROR [org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger] Job (DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean#1353154 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor] failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09180002 ]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:227)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException: Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor] failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09180002 
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09180002 
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:404)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:348)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrSearchService.query(SolrSearchService.java:152)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.SearcherComponent.query(SearcherComponent.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.AbstractSearcherComponent.query(AbstractSearcherComponent.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy13.query(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor$1$1.execute(FeedbackProcessor.java:92)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:259)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor$1.doWork(FeedbackProcessor.java:82)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:516)
    at org.alfresco.module.org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart.jobs.FeedbackProcessor.run(FeedbackProcessor.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:358)
    ... 28 more
```

The part that I think is causing this is...

```
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:358)
        ... 28 more
```

And in the Ephesoft terminal, I get the below error:

```
fatal transport error: connection refused: connect
```

I have looked up both the errors online, but a lot of the issues seems to say turn off your firewall, and our firewall is already disabled. I don't know if it makes a difference, but the older version of Alfresco is still there, but I moved it to the C:\OldAlfresco directory. Does anyone know why everything was fine before but now the two applications cannot run concurrently?

Comment: I was going to ask what Alfresco version, but just noticed from the logs that it's 4.1.1 - just to save anyone else asking...

Comment: A Windows version of `netstat` may be useful to confirm what ports are used by the two applications...

Comment: The error looks like Alfresco isn't finding SOLR to communicate with, do your have SOLR correctly setup and running?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about not including the version. But I tried the netstat command and didn't see anything particularly useful. And I believe we have always had that SOLR issue pop up in our logs, but it doesn't seem to be an actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to re-instal Alfresco after a trial.

You can do the following:

- follow the backup & restore procedure described [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Backup_and_Restore) . Just do
  the backup.
- delete the stuff you've back-upped (delete the content store, delete the DB, create a new DB, delete the indexes, not whole alf_data)
- just start Alfresco and you will have another 30 days.
- when you get your license just restore if you really need the data

P.S.: if you don't need the data you can skip step 1

And if you really want to install multiple instances, follow this [guide](http://www.appnovation.com/how-setup-multiple-instances-alfresco-different-ports)

Comment: I think I am going to give your recommendation a try and I'm having too many issues trying to get this separate instance working. And I tried following that guide, but my main question for that guide was, how can I change my ftp port to something other than 21? And if all I modify are the default and shutdown ports in alfresco and share, shouldn't that work the same?

Comment: In your alfresco-global.properties just add the following line: ftp.port=2121 hence your ftp port is now 2121 instead of the default 21. No you need to modify more ports for getting a runnable system. If you use the graphical installer it asks (advanced setup) for the corresponding ports and normally that's enough to get it started.

Comment: Yeah I tried changing all the port numbers as per the directions in that link, but it still looks like I can't get Alfresco to run concurrently with Ephesoft. Think I'm just going to have to restore and restart the trial on the first instance.